# why the below code is taking two input on single execution of scanf funcion

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int Dividend,divisor;

    printf("Checking Divisiblity of 1st number with 2nd number \n\n") ;

    printf("Enter Number \n") ;
    scanf("%d",&Dividend);

    printf("Enter Divisor = ");
    scanf("%d",&divisor) ;


    if(Dividend % divisor == 0)
    {
        printf("Number %d is divisible by %d",Dividend,divisor) ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number %d is not divisible by %d",Dividend,divisor) ;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my code that i have written in C ;

on running this program  . Only on first  execution  of scanf   function if i give two input  space seperated , the second input is going on right variable . and on hitting enter i am getting result . I am not understanding how is this happing .

Comment: Two of three tags are wrong.

Comment: Please don't tag irrelevant languages, this is neither c++ or Java

Comment: `scanf` is like that.  Your program asked for two numbers, you typed two numbers, the two `scanf` calls each got their number.  `scanf` doesn't know, or care, whether you hit Return between the two numbers — any whitespace will do.  So `scanf` is "working as designed" here.

Comment: If you want different behavior, you should [use something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).

Comment: To see just how strange `scanf` can be, try running your program, and when it says "Enter Number", hit Enter five times before you start typing the number.  (And then maybe hit Enter five more times before you type the divisor.)

Answer (score 1):

When space is pressed, `scanf` doesn't see anything yet. Something happens only after enter is pressed. It then takes everything to the left of the space character and assigns it to the first variable, and everything to the right of the space character and assigns it to the second variable.

If you don't press the spacebar, `scanf` will interpret everything you type as a single number and will assign it to the first variable.

Instead what you may want to do is use the `%c` format specifier to read a single character at a time. You can then check if the character is a space character and if it is, you can break out of the loop. Otherwise, you can keep reading characters until you reach a space character.

Comment: @hyde Ok I will edit my answer

Comment: No I want to take a multi digit Number but at the same time I also want that it will only take one input despite of giving multi space separated input on single enter hit.  Could you tell me how can I achieve this one

Answer (score 0):

`stdin` is line based by default. Your program gets nothing until you press enter. Then your program has the entire line of text available.

Result of this is, that `scanf`, `getchar`, `fgets`, etc calls will not return until you press enter. After enter press, entire line is available and the function starts to process it.

---

`scanf` is kinda special, that if you have `int parsed_count = scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);`, it will read *two* integers, no matter how many times you press enter, so you can either do

```
1 2<enter>
```

Or you can do

```
<enter>
1<enter>
<enter>
2<enter>
```

and `scanf` will still read these two integers (it returns early if there is parse error, which is why you need to check the return value!).

---

And vice versa, if there is already input available, then `scanf` may return immediately, so if you have this code

```
scanf("%d",&Dividend);
printf("Enter Divisor = ");
scanf("%d",&divisor) ;
```

and enter text

```
1 2<enter>
```

Then first scanf will wait for enter press, then consume the first integer, leaving  `2<enter>` still unread. Then there's print, and then 2nd scanf starts reading, skipping the whitespace and immediately getting 2nd integer. So you see

```
1 2  <- this is your typing echoed, not print from your program
Enter Divisor =   <- printf printed this
```

---

If you want to take only one input per enter press, you can simply read characters until newline, because `scanf` leaves them there. Example loop to read until newline, or exit program at end of file/error:

```
while(true) {
    int ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF) exit(1);
    if (ch == '\n') break;
}
```

Comment: sir can you just tell me how can i fix it that even after giving two input it won't take

Comment: @PrashantKumarGupta You mean, accept only one input number per enter press?

Comment: Yes  on each enter key press it take only one input8 even after giving it multiple space separated entry

Comment: @PrashantKumarGupta Simply read until end of line after calling `scanf`. See edit.

Comment: @PrashantKumarGupta My advice to you is: either don't worry about solving this "problem" (and I'm still not sure what the problem actually is), or if you must solve it, solve it by [using something other than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).  `scanf` is not inherently line-based, and trying to force it to operate rigidly on lines is more trouble than it's worth.